# phantom in environments

Tags: environments

I want to show a box that's equivalent to the space needed by the text (or figure). I have already the code below, but I can't seem to find a way to use `\phantom` in the environment to make the boxedminipage the right height.

```
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
...
\newenvironment{onblackboard}
{\begin{boxedminipage}{\linewidth}}
{\end{boxedminipage}}}
```

Using white font with `\color{white}` is not an option, because sometimes I have graphics in the environment, which I also do not want to show.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  (Also, I've removed the thank-you from your post - this is not seen as rude, but an attempt at conciseness within our community.  Upvoting and accepting answers is our way of saying thank-you!)

Comment: @kasi I do not understand what is wrong with the code you have provided. It produces a box around content just fine...?

Answer (score 4):

The environment contents can be stored in a box (`\onblackboardbox`) using environment `lrbox`. Because this environment uses horizontal mode, environment `minipage` switches back to vertical mode. We get the inner width by `\hsize`,
environment `boxedminipage` does not update `\linewidth`. Then the box is set by `\phantom` that only uses the dimension of the contents, the contents itself is not set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\newsavebox\onblackboardbox

\newenvironment{onblackboard}{%
  \begin{boxedminipage}{\linewidth}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\onblackboardbox}%
      \begin{minipage}{\hsize}% boxedminipage does not update \linewidth
}
{%
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \phantom{\usebox{\onblackboardbox}}%
  \end{boxedminipage}%
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{onblackboard}
    Hello World
  \end{onblackboard}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `boxedminipage` and it's easy to provide a *-variant that shows the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newsavebox\onblackboardbox
\newif\ifshowtext

\newenvironment{onblackboardinner}
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}% some vertical space
  \begin{lrbox}{\onblackboardbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}
 {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \noindent % now typeset the box
  \ifshowtext
    \fbox{\usebox{\onblackboardbox}}%
  \else
    \fbox{\phantom{\usebox{\onblackboardbox}}}%
  \fi
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
}

% onblackboard doesn't show the text
\newenvironment{onblackboard}
 {\showtextfalse\onblackboardinner}
 {\endonblackboardinner}

% onblackboard* shows the text
\newenvironment{onblackboard*}
 {\showtexttrue\onblackboardinner}
 {\endonblackboardinner}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{onblackboard}
  Hello World\\
  two lines\\
  three
\end{onblackboard}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{onblackboard*}
  Hello World\\
  two lines\\
  three
\end{onblackboard*}

\end{document}
```

[image]